# nextjs redirect page in 404 page in pathname constraints

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I want to constraint the users from directing to pages that were created in the `/pages/` path because for example if the user did direct to `http://localhost:3000/navbar` that would be ugly, but I have created a `/pages/navbar.tsx` in the file so my problem is that I want to redirect it to 404 page.

And I've found that I have to use `next-redirects` but I don't know how this things work.

Basically here's the code.

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import '@/styles/auth.scss'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// import accountSlice from '@/pages/features/Authentication';
import { store } from '@/features/Authentication';
import { AccountProvider } from '@/components/context/Account';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Redirects } from 'next-redirects';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/navbar') {
      Redirects('/', { statusCode: 404 });
    }
  }, []);
  

  return <>
    <AccountProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    </AccountProvider>
  </>
}
```

I followed the chatgpt instruction but it seems like the code is outdated. Anyone care helping me here how I can redirect it to 404 page? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ops, I'm sorry I just have to pass my navbar.tsx in `pages` into `components/navbar.tsx` so that it will receive an error.